# Mysterious whitespace in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

There's a mysterious whitespace along the right of my site in firefox (on both PC and Mac, latest versions) and I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing it.

This is what it looks like - [image]

I've been searching the CSS for ages now trying to figure out if it's some margin or padding issue but I can't find anything.
Also, if I remove the div ID 'slider3' the issue seems to disappear, yet I can't figure out how this div is causing the whitespace, since it has no CSS applied to it - it's simply a container.

Here's my site http://www.simplerweb.co.uk

Here's some relevant code so the answer is useful for people later on.

```
<div class="fullw">
<div class="sliderleft"></div>
<div class="sliderright"></div>



            <div id="slider3">
                <div class="quote">

                <div class="centmid">
                    <h1 class="fronth">Hello</h1>   
                    <h2 class="frontp">Welcome to Simpler Web</h2>
                    <h2 class="frontp2">We're an Edinburgh based Web<br> Design Agency</h2>
                </div><!-- end div centmid -->


                                </div> <!-- end div quotes1 -->
                <div class="quote2">
                <div class="centmid">
                    <h2 class="frontb">We make wonderful, cross platform <br> accessible Websites </h2>
                </div> <!-- end div centmid -->
                </div> <!-- end div quotes2 -->

                <div class="quote3">
                <div class="centmid">
                <h2 class="frontc">We can translate your ideas into reality </h2>
                </div> <!-- end div centmid -->
                </div><!-- end div quotes3 -->


            </div> <!-- #slider3 -->

</div>
```

CSS

/* The following styles are essential to the slider's functionality */

```
.plusslider {
    overflow: hidden;

    position: relative;
    padding-top: 140px; /* The height / width of the slider should never be set via the CSS. The padding increases the slider box-model while keeping it dynamic */
}

.plusslider-container { position: relative; }

/* Slides must have a set width - even though they may be dynamic. If no width is set on <img> slides, the default image size will be assumed */
div.child { width: 480px; }

.plusslider .child { float: left; }

/* PlusFader Specific (not needed with plustype:slider */
.plustype-fader .child { display: none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; }
.plustype-fader .current { z-index: 5; }
/* End PlusFader Specific */

/* No-javascript fallback -- change "#slider" and "#slider2" identifiers as needed for your html */
#slider > * { display: none; }
#slider > *:first-child, #slider2 > *:first-child { display: block; }
/* End no-javascript fallback */
```

/* End essential styles*/

/* The following styles are not essential for slider functionality. They are specific to the example content.
   It is important to note that the fading effect does not work correctly with non-image content unless that
   content area has a solid background (either a background image or a background-color, but not transparent).

```
Slides to not have to be the same width or height, but if you'd like a consistent width and/or height, make sure to set that within the CSS! */
#slider .slide1 { padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; } 
#slider .slide1 { height: 210px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; } 

.slide1 {  height: 500px; padding: 20px 40px; }
.slide1 h2 { color: #fff; font-size: 20px; margin: 0 0 20px 0; text-align: left; }
.slide1 p { border-left: 3px solid #fff; color: #fff; padding: 0 0 0 10px; }

.quote, .quote2, .quote3 { height:400px; padding: 20px 0; width: 980px;   width: 100%; position: relative; }
.quote { background-image: url(../images/weare.png); background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
.quote2 { background-image: url(../images/headlogosandroid.png); background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
.quote3 { background-image: url(../images/ideafront.png); background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; }

.plusslider a img { border: none; } /* Prevent blue borders in IE (not only does it look ugly, but it messes up spacing which breaks the "slider" type */

.plusslider-pagination { position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; }
.plusslider-pagination li { float: left; list-style: none; margin-left: 5px; }

#slider3 {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Comment: Oh and I should mention, the issue doesn't appear in any webkit based browsers or even IE, but it does appear in Opera.

Comment: What version of firefox?  I don't see an issue in 13.

Comment: I don't see it either (FF13, Linux) What do you see when you poke around the layout with the Firebug element inspector?

Comment: I don't see it either. FF12, Windows 7.

Comment: I see it in FF13. Disappears when I open Firebug to inspect it though.

Comment: Not an error for me too (Chrome, FF13, Opera on OSX)

Comment: Chrome, FF13 (Ubuntu). No issue.

Comment: I see the issue on Chrome. To me it seems a width problem. Anyway, just for your information, if you eraise from the "navcontainer" the position:fixed rule it seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Please include a minimal amount of relevant code directly in your question so that when your site changes or goes away, this question remains useful to future visitors.

Comment: I see it in Chrome 19. Disappears when I open Inspector to inspect it though.

Comment: @andy Why did you add the Opera tag? The question seems to not have anything to do with Opera.

Comment: @Rob W, I didn't add the opera tag, it seemed to have added it itself?

Oh and yes, the issue disappears when I try to use firebug, making it exceptionally hard to diagnose!

Comment: I don't see it in Win7, FF13. - or FF13.0.1

Comment: For those that don't see, you may see a horizontal scrollbar on the bottom.

Comment: @andy - See my answer if it helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (in FF) exactly **17px** extra width that is exactly the width of the browser scrollbar.

Your starting (initial) *loading black screen* (that animates) leaves a glitch of 17px:
cause it's animation maintains the DOM width that equals the `screen width` without the right scrollbar (100% screen width).
After the page is fully loaded and the scrollbar is added to the page, it actually adds the **extra** 17px (to the 100%) width that were maintained by the *Loading* animation.

Hope I put you in the right direction.

By the way, try to add:

```
html {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and - if still needed - adjust the *loading* element width as I mentioned before.

Comment: I initially thought the same thing, the page preloader was causing the issue, so I removed it and it remained.

And it is the exact width of the scrollbar.

overflow-y seems to solve the issue, thought I'm rather perplexed as to why it isn't overflow-x, since that's the horizontal axis?

Comment: @andy Simple: 1) The preloader is set to 100% : `HTML` initial rendered size = 100%. 2) content is added as it's loaded in the DOM and the browser adds the `y scrollbars` = 100%+17px **why?** cause the preloader animation is still running - maintaining the DOM HTML width at **100% + 17px** that results in the apperance of the `x scrollbar`.

Comment: BTW. adding a CSS `html{overflow-y:scroll;}` is a good thing in web design : doing that you prevent a *'jumpy'* page, added scrollbar to pages with more contents and pushing the page to the left to make space to the scrollbar creating this horrible effect while the user navigates. So in any case you're at bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Problem solved. (temporarily)

---

### So where is the problem?

It is at your `<div>` with the classes `plusslider slider3 plustype-slider`. You are constantly setting an incorrect width to it. You have to subtract the scrollbar width.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to do this: Padding: 0px(or whatever) 17px; and margin: 0px(or whatever) -17px; now your whitespace at the sides are gone.